# swfupload failing in my django runserver

Tags: python, django, swfupload

I have copied and pasted the code from http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/simpledemo/ into a django template, but when I upload a photo, the demo says "Server (IO) Error" before it actually uploads the entire file. The runserver is getting the request and returning a 200. Is there something I am missing here? What steps should I take to debug?

Thanks,
Collin Anderson

Comment: Do you receive the entire file on the Django server? Were there any other requests made to the server other than the main upload? I presume you changed the settings to point to your own back-end, what were those changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. I was uploading to a dummy view, and for some reason if you don't actually access request.POST or request.FILES it gives that error message.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have write permission to your server. In the folder you installed that thing. Check the user that is running runserver. If in windows - check folder is not readonly.